# Azure AD Graph API - does not provide option to enable multifactor authentication during user creation

Tags: azure, active-directory

Currently i am able to create user with multi-factor authentication enabled using "Azure management portal".

But when i am creating the user using Graph API, i don't find any option to enable multi-factor authentication in the REST contract.

Could you please help here. Or is there any alternative way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a program manager on the Azure Active Directory team at Microsoft.  This is currently not exposed through the AAD Graph.  I've added an item to our backlog to get it added.

thanks,
Vince

Comment: Thanks a lot Vince for the reply. Any tentative time frame which we can expect this feature, since we are planning to buy the premium version of Azure AD soon.

Comment: Hi Vince, Is this feature is available now as part of the new releases?